# probable word overuse in an introductory clause

Tags: redundancy

> "So, first things first. Let's check out the . . .."

In the preceding example, is the first clause redundant?

Comment: The English language, I am told, has more words than any other language on earth. Over a million. Consequently, there is bound to be more than a little redundancy in virtually every sentence we English speakers utter or write. To me, one of the most irritating sentences is the following:  "First of all, I would like to thank my mom and dad for encouraging me to . . .." Why not, "First: thanks, mom and dad, for encouraging me to . . ."? Sixteen words versus nine words. Then again, who's counting?

Answer (score 3):

It's a matter of judgement. The more formal you are striving to be, the more you would avoid phrases like that. "First things first" is informal, and unobjectionable, but you could replace it with, "First," without losing anything in meaning. And even in informal writing there are limits. Phrases like "Before we go any further let me start off by saying..." are just a waste of space in any kind of writing.

Answer (score 2):

It is not redundant.  "First things first" is a standard idiomatic phrase.  I'd punctuate it as follows:  First things first, let's check to see if we have gas in the tank before starting out on our trip.     The phrase is a casual one.

Comment: So are "casual phrases" like this one acceptable in formal letters or literary works like news articles?

Comment: 'So' is a connective pragmatic marker signalling a previous reason (either for the following statement in the matrix sentence or for the next pragmatic marker). 'First things first' is a fairly informal discourse-ordering marker.

Comment: coudn't that be treated as a casual connective to my earlier question?

Comment: So it could.  (Why did I not use a comma?)

Answer (score 0):

It is redundant in the sense that it does not add any useful information it itself and could be omitted, yet it has a function as a rhetoric device. Commonly it is used as a bridge after the introduction of the topic that will be discussed. Ideally, the audience's interest is now grabbed and they want to know more -- however before you can continue you need to cover some basics.

"First things first" therefore conveys useful information: it tells the audience to be patient with the following points before coming back to the interesting part.